# Ambigious call between methods

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try to pass data between activities and have error:

> C:\Users\nemesis\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\Menu Activities\SoupesActivity.cs(5,5): Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Android.Content.Intent.PutExtra(string, short)' and 'Android.Content.Intent.PutExtra(string, bool)' (CS0121) (MurakamiKiev)

Code in Activity 1:

```
private void ParseAndDisplay1(JsonValue json) {
    TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.posttittle);
    TextView price = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.price);
    TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.weight);
    productname.Click += delegate {
        var intent404 = new Intent (this, typeof(SoupesDetailActivity1));

        JsonValue firstitem = json [81];

        intent404.PutExtra ("title", firstitem ["post_title"]);
        intent404.PutExtra ("price", firstitem ["price"] + " грн");
        intent404.PutExtra ("weight", firstitem ["weight"] + "г");
        StartActivity (intent404);
    };
}
```

Code in Activity2 when I recieving attributes:

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json) {
    TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttitle);
    TextView content = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.postcontent);
    TextView price = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.price);
    TextView weight = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.weight);
    //JsonValue firstitem = json[81];

    productname.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("title");
    content.Text = firstitem["post_excerpt"];
    price.Text = firstitem["price"] + " грн";
    weight.Text = firstitem["weight"] + "г";
}
```

What's wrong in code?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonValue` inherits from `object`, when you are calling `intent404.PutExtra` the .NET does not know wich method he will call, to resolve your problem you just have to cast the object, like this:

```
intent404.PutExtra("title", (string)firstitem["post_title"]);
```

or

```
intent404.PutExtra("title", Convert.ToString(firstitem["post_title"]));
```

Json Value on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonvalue(v=vs.95).aspx

I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank's you helped me so much

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because compiler doesn't have enough data specified to understand which method to call.
To resolve your task, you have to explicitly specify your variable type in PutExtra method call:

```
intent404.PutExtra ("title", (firstitem ["post_title"]).ToString());
intent404.PutExtra ("price", (firstitem ["price"] + " грн").ToString());
intent404.PutExtra ("weight", (firstitem ["weight"] + "г").ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers show how to solve the problem, but the error message is confusing, so i will describe how that happens.

Consider this methods

```
private static void Bar(short value) { }
private static void Bar(bool value) { }
```

Compiler should decide what method to run and it is decided based on argument type.

Compiler will select first method :

```
short s = 0;
Bar(s);
```

Compiler will select second method :

```
bool b = true;
Bar(b);
```

In case compiler can't find suitable method for your argument type, it will give you an error:

```
object obj = new object();
Bar(obj);
```

> cannot convert from 'object' to 'short'

And you try to pass `firstitem ["post_title"]` as a method parameter. The type of this argument is [JsonValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673047%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The reason you get `ambiguous call` error is that `JsonValue`has [implicit cast operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Consider the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator short (Foo value)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool (Foo value)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Compiler can treat this class as `Foo`, as `Object`, as `short` and as `bool`, when choosing the suitable method. That is why you get an error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'Bar(object)' and 'Bar(short)'

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Bar(f);
```